# Canonical embedded interactive Python interpreter example?

Tags: python, c

I would like to create an embedded Python interpreter in my C/C++ application. Ideally this interpreter would behave exactly like the real Python interpreter, but yield after processing each line of input. The standard Python module `code` looks from the outside exactly like what I want, except that it is written in Python. E.g.:

```
>>> import code
>>> code.interact()
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jan  3 2011, 15:34:27) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

The core of `code` is the function that accepts potentially incomplete user input and either displays a syntax error (case 1), waits for more input (case 2), or executes the user input (case 3).

```
try:
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
except (OverflowError, SyntaxError, ValueError):
    # Case 1
    self.showsyntaxerror(filename)
    return False

if code is None:
    # Case 2
    return True

# Case 3
self.runcode(code)
return False
```

The example in the Python source tree `Demo/embed/demo.c` is the outer shell but not what I want because that example only handles complete statements. I'm including part of it here for reference:

```
/* Example of embedding Python in another program */
#include "Python.h"

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Initialize the Python interpreter.  Required. */
    Py_Initialize();
    [snip]
    /* Execute some Python statements (in module __main__) */
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n");
    [snip]
    /* Exit, cleaning up the interpreter */
    Py_Exit(0);
}
```

What I'm looking for is the C code to handle incomplete blocks, stacktraces, etc. That is, all the behaviors of the real Python interpreter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html#python.using_the_interpreter). It's a fantastic integretaion of Python in C++ and vice versa.

But you are able to use the C API anyway. The [PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags()](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags) function offer a interactive console in your C++ application.

Comment: Boost.Python is a great library, but it doesn't have an embedded interactive interpreter. In `boost/python/exec.hpp` there are functions for evaluating Python code, `eval`, `exec`, and `exec_file`, but none of these is for interactive use.

Comment: Yes, but boost.python is not a 100% replacement for the C API. In your case use the PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags() (http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags) function to lunch the interactive console.

Comment: Raphael, could you please elevate your comment to a response? I see now that there's also PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags that proceeds a statement at a time. It's missing the error printing code, but that may be available somewhere else.